# How to dynamically squeeze multiple columns to one in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have data with blank cells in between and I am looking for a way to squeeze them into one column.

[image: Expected result from the data on the right]

Since the number of rows can change and the number of columns can change, too, I am looking for a dynamic way to this. I have already managed to do it in a non-dynamic way using the following formula but I am really interested in a dynamic way.

```
=IFS(COUNTA($B2:2)=1, TEXTJOIN("",true, $B2:2), COUNTA($B2:2)>1, "AMBIGUOUS")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(
 INDIRECT("B2:"&ROWS(B:B)), " ", "♦")),,999^99)))), " "), "ambiguous", 
 SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(
 INDIRECT("B2:"&ROWS(B:B)), " ", "♦")),,999^99))), "♦", " ")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you! This does actually do the job. I've been trying to figure out how it works to adapt it to my needs, but I am struggling. Do you mind elaborating on how this works?

Comment: sure, basically it concentrates all columns from B column into one column via `TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE( ),,999^99)` this adds empty space between columns so on 6th row the joined value will be `tag2 tag3` so we try to detect this empty space and if present then output `ambiguous`. if space not present means there is only one value on that row so that value gets outputed